# Advantage of integer type over string field type in elastic search

Tags: elasticsearch, lucene

I am wondering what are the other advantages except type validation of integer field type in comparison to string type. As far as I know in Lucene index those fields anyway are stored in common byte format.

The reason why I am asking is that I have a field value which can be both string and integer. I am thinking about should I create different types inside a mapping, i.e. `localhost:9200/index/string_type` and `localhost:9200/index/integer_type` or I can safely (in terms of performance and other aspects) use string type for both variants.

I am using elastic 2.4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could go with the **string_type** for both actually. I don't personally see any advantages of having an **interger_type** over the string. But then make sure that you map the `string` as *not_analyzed*, hence the value of the field will not be analyzed or tokenized. So that you could simply use the field for *aggregations*. Maybe you should have a look at this [one](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/aggregations-and-analysis.html#_analyzed_strings_and_fielddata) which elaborates more. Having both the field types at once would not make any difference at all from doing the above.

Comment: I am going to search for those string fields, so, I would like to apply standard analyzer as the string has unknown content.